# What ways are there of drawing 3D trees using Java and OpenGL?

Tags: java, c++, c, opengl, procedural-generation

I know how to draw basic objects using JOGL or LWJGL to connect to OpenGL. What I would like is something that can generate some kind of geometry for trees, similar to what SpeedTree is famous for. Obviously I don't expect the same quality as SpeedTree.

I want the trees to not look repetitive. Speed is not a concern, I do not expect to need more than 100 trees on screen at one time.

Are there free tree-drawing libraries available in Java? Or sample code or demos?
Is there anything in other languages which I could port or learn from?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

http://arbaro.sourceforge.net/

http://www.propro.ru/go/Wshop/povtree/povtree.html

Non java: http://www.aust-manufaktur.de/austt.html

Comment: I don't see the javadoc for arbaro but you can always get the source and generate it yourself. Good luck.

Answer (score 2):

There are thousands of methods. A better question would define 'best' in a more confined way. Are we talking 'best' as in speed of drawing (suitable for thousands or millions of trees)? Best as in best-looking? etc.

Answer (score 2):

2D or 3D?
In 2D, a common way is to use L-systems.
I also tried an OO approach, defining objects for trunk, branches, leaves, all extending an abstract class and implementing a Genotype interface (to vary the kind of trees).
Not sure if it is efficient (lot of objects created, particularly if I animate the tree) but interesting to do.

Answer (score 1):

Here are a couple resources that may be helpful:

- [gamedev thread on the subject](http://www.gamedev.net/community/forums/topic.asp?topic_id=157049) - contains some useful advice/suggestions
- [ngPlant](http://ngplant.sourceforge.net/) - an open-source procedural plant generation tool. It is not written in Java, but you may be able to find ideas in its algorithms.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using eclipse/SWT, try Draw 2D.

Answer (score 0):

If you're serious about getting good-looking, fast trees, there's a commercial C++ library [SpeedTree](http://www.speedtree.com/html/speedtreert.htm). Lots of big-time games use it (e.g., GTA, Elder Scrolls).

Comment: SpeedTree is amazing, but I am planning some software that will be free and open source (probably GPL licensed) and so I need to either find a free solution or make my own.

Answer (score 0):

A combination of OpenSceneGraph and SpeedTree has worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

I know of two libraries that enable the usage of OpenGl with java.

[LWJGL](http://lwjgl.org/) (Light Weight Java Gaming Library), which imo is the better one due to its simplicity and its similarity to using opengl with c/c++.

[JOGL](https://jogl.dev.java.net/) If you want to mix swing components with opengl this may be the better choice, I've never used it but several years ago it was known to be pretty buggy, I don't know if its matured since then.

As for drawing trees, there are many ways to do so like the other poster said, you might want to be more specific.

edit: I guess I misunderstood the question a bit, oh well : /  You can load in a 3d model of a tree and display that.

Answer (score 0):

http://www.codeplex.com/LTrees has some source code on that. it's c++ though.